# Failed to resolve: com.github Affected Modules

Tags: java, android, lib

I like to include a Calendar in my App. So I try to implement Roboto Calendar View. After implement:

```
 dependencies {

    implementation  'com.github.marcohc:robotocalendarview:<release>'

}
```

And:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

}
}
```

I got the Error: Failed to resolve: com.github
Affected Modules. What did I wrong?

Comment: change implementation  'com.github.marcohc:robotocalendarview:<release>' to implementation  'com.github.marcohc:robotocalendarview:3.6.1' and retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   implementation  'com.github.marcohc:robotocalendarview:<release>'
```

Here `<release>` means latest version currently available to download . which is `3.6.1` . So change your dependency like this

> implementation  'com.github.marcohc:robotocalendarview:3.6.1'